# Open camera in part of screen

Tags: android

I want open camera not full screen. I want open in a particular position on the screen inside one rectangle.

Maybe a surface? I don't know.

How can I do?

I want camera in my view. For example in a rectangle in center of screen. And when I push a button Take a pic

Comment: Please be more specific .. You need to float a view on your home screen which shows camera in it **OR** you want this functionality in your app (just like video playing in youtube android application in right bottom corner) ?

Comment: I want camera in my view. For example in a rectangle in center of screen. And when I push a button Take a pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use surface view with camera preview for [this](http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/10/displaying-camera-preview-instant.html).
[This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) may help you.