# Android: add camera inside another view

Tags: android

I want add camera in my main view but not open full screen. For example I want a rectangle with camera in center of my screen

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for an app oooor are you just using android? What are you trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open camera in part of screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144013/open-camera-in-part-of-screen)

Comment: The camera will show wherever its `SurfaceView` is located. `SurfaceView` is just a normal view, position it and set its size with layouts.